# Pass object to task scheduler

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2's [task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling). I need to be able to pass two options to the scheduler, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is what I have in my `Kernel.php`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('simple_cron --first_option=10')
        ->everyMinute();
}
```

And this in my `simple_cron` command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use App\Models\Article;

class SimpleCron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'simple_cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = '';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $firstOption = $this->option('first_option');
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
The "--first_option" option does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [offical documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan) the first thing is that your signature needs to have one/two placeholders for parameters:

```php
protected $signature = 'simple_cron {p1} {p2} {--firstoption=5}';
```

Here we set a default value of `5` for the option `firstoption`. If you don't want a default value just write `{--firstoption=}`

To fetch those parameters in your `handle` method you can do it like that:

```php
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $p1 = $this->argument('p1'); // should be 10
    $p2 = $this->argument('p2'); // should be 20
    $option1 = $this->option('firstoption'); // should be 99

    //
}
```

You should then be able to call it like this:

```php
$schedule->command('simple_cron 10 20 --firstoption=99')->daily();
```

Comment: That's for arguments, but what about options?

Comment: @user6328591 I updated my answer with an option example.